# Issue with node-scheduler not working in Next.js app deployed on Vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I've developed a Next.js application that uses node-scheduler for automating tasks. These tasks function as intended on my localhost, but when I deployed the application to Vercel, the node-scheduler functionality stopped working. I suspect that this could be due to timeout execution limits in the serverless environment of Vercel.

How can I confirm if timeout limits are causing this issue? Additionally, what strategies or modifications can I implement to ensure that the node-scheduler tasks continue to work in the Vercel environment?

Furthermore, if Vercel proves to be incompatible with this specific scheduling requirement, could you suggest alternative hosting platforms that better support node-scheduler and Next.js applications?

I've thoroughly reviewed my code and configuration to ensure there are no errors or inconsistencies affecting the node-scheduler setup.
I've checked the Vercel logs, but there are no explicit error messages related to the node-scheduler tasks.
I suspect that the tasks might be getting terminated due to timeout restrictions in the Vercel environment, but I'm unsure how to confirm this and how to resolve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.